# Subpages List Appearing on Every Page

Tags: sub-menu, wp-list-pages

This code displays the parent page and a list of its subpages, but not the grandparent page. (It is the second red menu in the left sidebar [here](http://themeforward.com/demo2/practice-areas/criminal-law/)).

There is one problem with this. This code outputs a list of **all pages on the website** if the user is **on a post or archives page** ([see here](http://themeforward.com/demo2/category/blog/)).

How do I prevent this from happening? This code is big and clunky, is there an easier solution? Thanks for the help.

```
<?php //parent variables
    $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $parent_title = get_the_title($parent);
    $grandparent = $parent->post_parent;
    $grandparent_title = get_the_title($grandparent);
    $current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );?>

<?php // is the homepage the granparent? = third level page
if ($grandparent == is_page('0')) {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // list the parent page
    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // append the list of children pages to the same $children variable
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <?php echo $children; /*print list of pages*/ ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }?>

<?php // is the homepage the parent? = second level page
    } elseif ($post->post_parent ==is_page('0')) {
      $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
  if ($children) { ?>

    <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></li>
      <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    } else {// your else stuff

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this for pages only, which would makes sense as to what you described this, just wrap the whole bunch of code in `if ( is_page() ) { ... }`.

If you were to put this into a function, you could just bail out early.

```
function wpdev_156446_list_parent_page_tree() {

    if ( ! is_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Your above code here
}
```

**// EDIT**

```
function wpdev_156446_list_parent_page_tree() {

    if ( ! is_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
    $parent_title = get_the_title($parent);
    $grandparent = $parent->post_parent;
    $grandparent_title = get_the_title($grandparent);
    $current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

    // is the homepage the granparent? = third level page
    if ($grandparent == is_page('0')) {
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // list the parent page
        $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); // append the list of children pages to the same $children variable
        if ($children) {
            ?>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <?php echo $children; /*print list of pages*/ ?>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }

    // is the homepage the parent? = second level page
    } elseif ($post->post_parent ==is_page('0')) {
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
        if ($children) {
            ?>
            <ul>
              <li class="current_page_item"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></li>
              <?php echo $children; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php
        } else {// your else stuff

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I receive errors. Perhaps I am doing this incorrectly. I have inserted my code where that code says to...

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the negation `!` in the function. I updated that. Also, please include any errors/warnings/notices to your questions to help us all sort this out.

Comment: This is how I did it: http://snippi.com/s/o8vu44e
I'm probably way off. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in on line 48

Comment: Thank you, but now it's not appearing on pages either. :-/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there either is something else going on, or you are not looking at a page but some other template.

Comment: You **do** call the function somehwere (in your sidebar or so), right?

Comment: I'm calling exactly what you provided in the edit in my sidebar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16119/discussion-between-t-f-and-andrettimilas).